# Construct a triangle given a height, his base and the opposite angle

Tags: geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

Let $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ be given segments  and $\alpha$ a given angle.

Construct the triangle $ABC$ with height $\overline{CD}$ corresponding to the side $\overline{AB}$, such that $\angle BCA=\alpha$.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Parallel translate the sample angle onto $AB$. You get a point $C'$ that looks at $AB$ with angle $\alpha$, which is not yet the solution. Draw the circle passing through $ABC'$. Then draw a parallel line to $AB$ at distance $CD$. $C$ is the intersection of the circle and the parallel line. Let me know is you don't know how to further break down the previous steps into more elementary actions.

Comment: Parallel or perpendicular @orole

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Parallel translation. Presumably the angle is given by giving two lines that intersect at that angle. One needs to draw through $A$ and $B$ lines parallel to the given lines.

Comment: @orole you said that a parallel line to $AB$ at distance $CD$. Shouldn't it be perpendicular (I personally have no idea)?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yes, draw a line parallel to $AB$ that lies is at a distance $CD$ from $AB$. This can be done, among many other ways, by lifting perpendiculars to $AB$ at $A$ and $B$ and marking on them the distance $CD$. Then joining the marks one gets the parallel line we want.

Comment: @orole I thought $D$ lied on $AB$ and that was counter intuitive for me. SOrry, my bad.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan $D$ lies on $AB$. But when I say distance $CD$ I mean the distance. Presumably, a distance is given by giving a segment somewhere that has the length wanted. Most likely they don't give the very segment $CD$ otherwise there is nothing to be done.

Comment: @NotAMathematician Take into account that there are choices that can be made in the construction. In general there can be up to $4$ triangles as solution, although all congruent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the middle of $AB$, let's call this $M$, and draw the perpendicular to $AB$ through $M$. From angle $\alpha$ we can find the angle $90^\circ-\alpha$. From $AB$ construct this angle, and call $O$ the intersection with the perpendicular through $M$. The angle $\angle AOM=\alpha$, and then the angle $\angle AOB=2\alpha$. Draw a circle with the center at $O$, and radius $OA$. All the points $N$ on the circle, on the $O$ side of the $AB$ line have $\angle ANB=\alpha$. I used the fact that the inscribed angle is half the arc, and that  the arc equal to the central angle. Now on the $MO$ line draw a point $P$ at a distance $DC$ from $M$, on the same side as $O$, then draw a parallel to $AB$ through $P$. From all points on this parallel line, the perpendicular to $AB$ had the length $DC$. Now the intersections of the line with the circle obey both conditions in the problem.

Comment: Nice answer! However, I think in the third line you meant angle $\angle AOM$, since $\angle OAM=90°-\alpha$.

Comment: Correct. My mistake. I'll fix it